# Pik on Windows 7 doesn't remember the selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pik

I am using `pik` on Windows 7. I am unable to make `pik` to remember the ruby version selection.

Example:

**Command Window 1**

```
> pik list
* 187: ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i386-mingw32]
  192: ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]
  193: ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]
```

I select version 193.

```
>pik 193
>pik list
  187: ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i386-mingw32]
  192: ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]
* 193: ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]
```

Now I launch another command window:

**Command Window 2**

```
> pik list
* 187: ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i386-mingw32]
  192: ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]
  193: ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]
```

In the new window the ruby selection is not remembered. How do I make `pik` persist the ruby selection across command window sessions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pik is not loaded when you open a new command prompt. Because of that, it is unable to *default* to some Ruby interpreter for a new window.

To have one particular Ruby interpreter in the PATH you will need to modify your user or system PATH so it is available always.

Later you can use Pik to change the version of Ruby to the one you desire.

However, you can setup a *default* Ruby so you can do `pik default` to use that one. See `pik help use` for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that pik defaults to the `Ruby` that that is defined in your System's `Path` variable.

So to change the default `Ruby` you would need to change your System's `Path` Variable to your  preferred choice of `Ruby`.